# HTML link to itself with GET

Tags: php, html, get

I want to create a number of links within a page that have different GET parameters.  However, I want the page that is called to be the current page.

```
<a href="ITSELF?param1=123&param2=345">Link1</a>
<a href="ITSELF?param1=234&param2=345">Link2</a>
```

Where "ITSELF" is the page currently loaded.  I'd rather not include a hard link to a specific page location as this PHP can potentially be loaded from different URLs.

Suggestions?

-Jonathan

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just don't put the ITSELF in there and it will do what you want, e.g.

```
<a href="?param1=123&param2=345">Link1</a>
```

Note that this will only include the path, not the query params, so if your current script is at `/foo/bar?a=b`, the link referred to will be `/foo/bar?param1=123&param2=345`.  If you want to include the `a=b` as well, you'll need to figure it out server side.